# Cant figure out how to download youtube video through python

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, beautifulsoup, youtube-dl

I am trying to make a program which can download the first link in a youtube search through python. I am using bs4 to scrape the HTML and youtube-dl to download the first link. For some reason, it doesn't get past the os.system command. It doesn't give any errors and just exits with exit code 1.

Here's my code(using python 2.7.1 on windows 10):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import os


search = raw_input("What do you want to search?: ")
search2 = search.replace(" ", "+")
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search2 + "&page=&utm_source=opensearch"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    a = link.get('href')
    b = a[:6]
    if (b == "/watch"):
        print " "
        print "First link: " + a
        page = "youtube.com/" + a
        command = "youtube-dl " + str(page)
        os.system("cd C:/Python27/Scripts/" | command)
        print "Done!"

        break

    print a
```

Comment: The argument of `os.system` is invalid - the pipe character doesn't work this way for strings in Python. Try `"cd C:/Python27/Scripts/ & " + command`.

Comment: When I do this, it gives an error saying youtube-dl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. Even though I have youtube-dl in the system32 folder and in the scripts folder.

Comment: You could actually use youtube-dl [directly from python](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl)

Comment: I have tried using it directly but it doesn't seem to be working. It says ffprobe or avprobe not found

Comment: I have figured out the problem. It was trying to convert it to an mp3 at the end which requires ffmpeg.